# dimension of intersection of subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

In a *13-dimensional* vector space, the dimension of intersection of two *6-dimensional* subspaces is

- at least 1
- at most 1
- at least 6
- at most 6

**My thought**:For two subspaces ***U*** and ***W*** of vector space ***V***, *6≦dim(U+W)≦12*.

Using the result
**dim(U∩W)=dim(U)+dim(W)-dim(U+W)**; I got  *0≦dim(U∩W)≦6*. Am I right?

Comment: Yes it seems reasonable.

Comment: mathreadler......thanks